# Proving convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have a sequence of functions of the form $\varphi_k: T \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $\varphi_k(z) = z^{n_k}e^{\psi_k(z)}$ where $T$ is the unit circle, and $\psi_k \in C(T)$.

I know that $||\varphi_k-\varphi||_{\infty} \longrightarrow 0$ for $\varphi \in C(T)$.  I'm trying to show that $\varphi = z^ne^{\psi}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\psi \in C(T)$.

In order to do this I need to show that $z^{n_k} \longrightarrow z^n$ and that $\psi_k \longrightarrow \psi$ uniformly, but I'm not sure how to prove this given only that $z^{n_k}e^{\psi_k} \longrightarrow \varphi$.

Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. If $\psi_k(z)=-k$ for all $k,z$ then $\psi_k \to 0$ uniformly and you cannot write $0=z^{n}e^{\psi (z)}$.